Extract BW/4HANA using Python vs exporting data directly
I am trying to explore the option of exporting data from BW/4HANA to AWS S3 in flat file format.
I have two options

Open Hub
Use Python

I checked with SAP BW consultant in my company. He said I can't use Open Hub as it will result in truncation of data and is meant only for small files.
Is it true?
Second option is to use Python. I am concerned with license requirements here. Can we extract data using Python? Hopefully we won't broke any license agreements by SAP.
Please comment on both options.
